# How to remove Report Server Web Service URLs from Reporting Service Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

To start with, I am completely new to SSRS reporting. Please excuse me if I miss any basic details here.
I am trying to create a reporting service.
Accidently, I have selected an existing Report Server Web Service Site Identification.
Now I have 2 Web service URLs. HTTP and one HTTPS
**I want to remove the HTTPS URL.** But I am not getting any option to do that.
To have a clear picture, I am adding the images below.
[image: This is the url I want to remove]
[image: Not getting any link to remove]
Kindly help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try restarting the SSRS service and see if the https url goes away?

An alternative may be to try editing the [rsreportserver.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rsreportserver-config-configuration-file) file directly and remove any references to the https url under `<URL> </URL>` for the following:

```
<URLReservations>
        <Application>
            <Name>ReportServerWebService</Name>
            <VirtualDirectory>ReportServer</VirtualDirectory>
            <URLs>
```

again, the SSRS service will have to be restarted for changes to take effect.